# Flutter: DropDownMenuItem - How to access i or index

Tags: flutter, methods, iteration, dropdown

I am trying to access my counter variable **i** OR the current **index** of the current item, but it seems impossible.

```
items: listeZutatenDropdown[i].map((String value) {     
                                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                                    value: value,
                                    child: (value == "Zutat auswählen") ? new Text("Zutat auswählen") : new Text(value + " " + i.toString()),
                                  );
                                }).toList()
```

If I print i out as I do in my code example, I always get 0. (does that have to do with the scope of the return statement?).

If I try to use index as additional parameter, I get "The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<DropdownMenuItem>?'" and "The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<DropdownMenuItem>?'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)
The argument type 'DropdownMenuItem Function(int, String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(String)'" which confuses me because I see people using the .map() method as well as the .forEach() method all the time, but when I want to use them....^^

Lastly, I tried to save i in a variable and to access this variable in my return statement. Same outcome as before (0).

Hope you can tell me what I am doing wrong! Looking forward to your feedback!

Regards
Thomas

Comment: Are you trying to get the index of `value` or the `I` variable you;ve used on code

Comment: Your question seems unclear. Is u want to get selected dropdown value of the i(th) index like it seem you are showing dropdown from list of list of item as you have used "listeZutatenDropdown[i]". If you want to get selected value you should call   onChanged: (String? newValue) {} method in dropdown button and store results of selected dropdowns in list of same listeZutatenDropdown length to map and get value of each dropdown with respect to i.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I am fine with whatever I can get, no matter if it's value or I.

Comment: @Dr_Usman I do not know why I should move to onChanged if I want to generate the DropdownMenuItems right away. So my question is, how to get the index of value or how to access i from within the return statement.

Comment: You cant get index on return, items only take `DropdownMenuItem`list.  It would be better if you describe a little more what exactly you are trying to archive

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I am only trying to display two different values (the name of an ingredient and the unit) in an DropdownMenuItem. The first one works just fine, but as I tried to display the second one, which should not be big of a deal since I (as I thought) got the counter variable I AND possiblity even the index of the iteration...but well, whatever I try and do, it does not work. I am trying a workaround right now, where I access another field in the database that already combines both values, but that looks dirty to me because the first approach has to work somehow as well.

Comment: Sorry, but you are already providing index on Text, also dropDownItem value cant be changed and only takes unique value. you can try inline function and am not getting without the code , IF it is possible , you can upload the the minimal code-snippet that will reproduce the same error

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I solved it differently now. Was already generating my listZutatenDropdown this way (listeZutatenDropdown = List<List<String>>.generate(listZutaten.length, (i) => List<String>.generate(listZutaten.length, (i) => listZutaten[i]));), so I just created a new List and combined both. Not quiet the way I wanted it to work, but solved the problem. Thanks for your help though! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since I was not able to access my counter variable nor the index, I just copied the code I already had for my listZutatenDropdown

```
listeZutatenDropdown = List<List<String>>.generate(listZutaten.length, (i) => List<String>.generate(listZutaten.length, (i) => listZutaten[i]));
```

and added the list of units

```
listeZutatenUndEinheiten = List<List<String>>.generate(listZutaten.length, (i) => List<String>.generate(listZutaten.length, (i) => listZutaten[i] + " (" + listEinheiten[i] + ")"));
```

Not the cleanest way in my opinion, because I would prefer to go with the counter variable OR the index to reduance unnecessary code, but it works.